# Automapper and ViewModels and Posting Updates back to database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, automapper

I keep readin that you should use ViewModels (and AutoMapper) - so this is my initial steps into that.

I'm just looking for some reassurance that I'm mapping my model to my viewmodel, and when posted back, that I'm then updating the database record correctly, from the returned viewmodel:

```
    //
    // GET: /Customer/EditPartial
    public ActionResult EditPartial(int id)
    {
        var customerVM = db.Customers.Where(x => x.UserName == User.Identity.Name && x.CustomerId == id).FirstOrDefault();
        AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<Customer, CustomerViewModel>();
        CustomerViewModel customer = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<Customer, CustomerViewModel>(customerVM);
        return PartialView("CustomerPartial2", customer);
    }

    //
    // POST: /Customer/EditPartial
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult EditPartial(CustomerViewModel customerviewmodel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            Customer customer = db.Customers.Where(x => x.UserName == User.Identity.Name && x.CustomerId == customerviewmodel.CustomerId).FirstOrDefault();
            if (customer == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            customer.CustomerName = customerviewmodel.CustomerName;
            customer.Email = customerviewmodel.Email;
            db.Entry(customer).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return PartialView("CustomerPartial2", customerviewmodel);
    }
```

So, is my Get setting up Automapper correctly?

And is the way I am updating the CustomerName and Email from the viewmodel correct, or is there a simpler way using AutoMapper again?

Thank you,

Mark

Comment: The set up looks fine except for the naming of your variables (customerVM corresponds to a Customer entity and customer corresponds to a view model). You can also use automapper in the post method to map the vm to the customer entity back.

Comment: Is there a problem you're encountering? If not, this should be posted on http://codereview.stackexchange.com instead.

Comment: Thanks - not a problem - just I wasn't sure how to use AutoMapper in the POST - the way I've done it seems to not make use of AutoMapper at all.

Answer (score 1):

If you getting your mapping done correctly, you're using it correctly. AutoMapper can be used in get and post regardless. Its sole purpose in life is to map your one class to your another class (in your particular case domain model into view model and vise versa). If mapping is correct (in the debugger), you're OK. If not - let us know what problem are you experiencing.

If you not sure how to use it please refer to this article: [Simplify Your Projections with AutoMapper](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2012/02/01/simplify-your-projections-with-automapper.aspx) from Visual Studio Magazine.

Here is another specific to ASP.NET MVC: [Using Automapper with ASP.NET MVC application](http://tecexplorer.blogspot.ca/2013/01/using-automapper-with-aspnet-mvc.html).

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As AutoMapper intended for conciseness I think this code would be more elegant:

```
//
    // POST: /Customer/EditPartial
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult EditPartial(CustomerViewModel customerviewmodel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            Customer customer = db.Customers.Where(x => x.UserName == User.Identity.Name && x.CustomerId == customerviewmodel.CustomerId).FirstOrDefault();
            if (customer == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            Mapper.CreateMap<CustomerViewModel , Customer>();
            Mapper.Map(customerviewmodel, customer);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return PartialView("CustomerPartial2", customerviewmodel);
    }
```

In your code there is no much manual property assigning but there might be cases where you will have to type a lot using your approach.